# I would like for my program to respond based on user input

Tags: python

My goal is for my program to reply differently based on how I respond to the question "how are you today?" if I said good, bad, or What? then the program would respond respectively.

The way I went about this was putting all the synonyms for "good" "bad" as well as question triggers, (who, what, when, etc.) into 3 sets. I tried to make it so that if the program detected one of the words from the set then it would respond with the attached print command.

However, what happens is it will ask me how my day was, I will respond, and it will say "press any key to continue" pressing any key exits the program. it does not comment on my input.

I'm very new to coding so I apologize.

Here is the code I am using.

````
response = input () 
question = {"?","who","what","when","where","why","how"}
happyfeeling = {"ok","good","alright","average","happy","cheerful","content","delighted","ecstatic","elated","glad","overjoyed","joyous","pleasant","joyful","jubilant","lively","merry","peaceful","pleased","thrilled","upbeat","blessed","blissfull","chipper"}
sadfeeling = {"bad","depressed","not good","not happy","not alright","not cheerful","not content","not delighted","not glad","sad","bitter","dismal","abysmal","heartbroken","blue","dejected","mournful","pessimistic","somber","sorry","wistful","unhappy"}
if response == question:
    print("that is a question")
    if response == happyfeeling:
        print("I'm glad to hear that")
        if response == sadfeeling:
            print("I'm sorry to hear that")```
````

Comment: Change all `==` to `in`. Then, you will get response for `'what'`. All other `if`s are nested inside, which I think should be `elif`s to first `if`.

Comment: Yes that worked! thank you so much